# AngularJS how to use $scope.$broadcast inside Directive Link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs, I would like to know how can I use broadcast inside my Directive Link, Please take a look, Thank You,

Here is my directive,

```
myApp.directive("displayArticleDivDirective", function($parse,$rootScope) {
        return {
            scope: {
              id: "=",
              status: "@"
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                var clickingCallback = function() {
                var id = $scope.id;
                var status = $scope.status;

                    console.log(id); /* id is displayed */

                    $scope.$broadcast("ScopeDisplayArticleDiv",{ id: id , article_status: status}); /* this does not execute, nothing happens here */

              };
              $element.bind('click', clickingCallback);
            }
        };
    });
```

Here is my listener `.$on`

```
$scope.$on("ScopeDisplayArticleDiv", function(event,target){
            /* Nothing Happens Here */
                console.log('test'); 
});
```

The `ScopeDisplayArticleDiv` wont broadcast, it wont fire and there's no error on my console. I dont know why its not firing,
A working sample would be highly appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: Why do you need to broadcast? its a directive and you can directly update the using_controller's scope

Comment: use rootScope.$broadcast

Comment: both of your suggestions worked, i tried it both, i dnt know why i had to use $broadcast, i might have overlooked into that, my primary goal was to call a function inside a directive,

Comment: @apelidoko good to know it worked. You can also call controller functions using $scope.$parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing $broadcast to $emit.

They both function very similarly, but $broadcast sends a message down the scope hierarchy, whereas $emit sends it upwards. Assuming your listener is on your controller, or at least above the scope of the directive, that should do the trick.

here's more info on it: 
http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx

and a photo from that link depicting what I was describing:
http://www.dotnettricks.com/img/angularjs/emit-broadcast.png

EDIT: alternatively, you could pass a callback function into the directive that would be called each time the click handler is processed.

```
myApp.directive("displayArticleDivDirective", function($parse,$rootScope) {
    return {
        scope: {
          id: "=",
          status: "@",
          callbackFn: "&?"
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            var clickHandler = function() {
                var id = $scope.id;
                var status = $scope.status;
                if(callbackFn){
                    callbackFn({ id: id , article_status: status});
                }

                console.log(id); /* id is displayed */
          };

          $element.bind('click', clickHandler);
        }
    };
});

$scope.someFunction = function(status)
    //status is passed from inside the directive and this function is run
    //from the parent scope, not the directive scope.
    console.log('test'); 
});

<display-article-div-directive id={{article.id}} status={{article.status}} callback-fn={{someFunction}}></display-article-div-directive>
```

This would allow an optional callback to be passed to the directive to be triggered when handling a click. Also, you may want to use "<" when binding the id, as the "=" means that you could potentially change the id registered to the directive from the parent controller. I don't know if that was your intention, but I would think an id would be unchanging throughout the lifecycle of the directive instance.